# Structs Conforming to AnyObject

Tags: arrays, swift

I was writing some code when I came across something which contradicted what I had been taught when I first learned Swift. Somebody had told me that Swift can automatically bridge between structs and AnyObject. However, when I wrote code similar to this, I got an error. The error had something to do with "Hello" not conforming to the type AnyObject. Somebody please help.

`var someArray = [AnyObject]()
someArray.append("Hello")`

Comment: "when I wrote code similar to this..." - post the code you actually wrote, not some different code merely "similar to" it. "I got an error. The error had something to do with..." - post the actual error you got, not a vague prose description of it.

Comment: This was true (in practice) for Swift < 3.0. Now you can use Any to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Up until Swift 2.3, when Foundation is imported, common struct types can be implicitly bridged to their Foundation counterparts when they're coerced into being `AnyObject`.

In a move to distance Swift from Foundation, this implicit behaviour is now required to be explicit in Swift 3, using the coercion (`as`) operator.